# To enable pings between 2 VMs in a subnet, Should I configure an inbound or outbound rule in an Azure Network Security Group?

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

I have 2 virtual machines (say 'A', 'B') in a subnet within a virtual network.
In the future, I can have multiple VMs in the same subnet.

I want to ensure that only virtual machine 'A' can ping 'B'.
Should I create an Inbound security role in the NSG (Network Security Group) with Source as A's private IP, protocol as ICMP, rule as "Allow", and destination as B's private IP?

Or

Should I be creating an Outbound rule in NSG with the same configuration as explained above for the inbound rule?

I see configuring the Inbound rule is the solution. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Go to VM B's NSG -> Inbound rule -> Add  1) Source = IP Addresses 2)
> Source IP addresses/CIDR ranges = private ip address of VM A 3) Source
> port ranges = 22 4) Destination = Any 5) Service = Custom 6) Protocol
> = ICMP 7) Action = Deny
>
> This will block all ping request from VM A to VM B, if you want to block and
> ip ranges you can also paste it on number 2 section.